# Internal server error - CSRF token has expired - wsgi error file csrf.py line 110 csrf validation SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: flask, csrf, mod-wsgi, flask-wtforms

Issues deploying a flask app using WSGI and Apache server over Ubuntu 18.04

Issues:

- Trying to load the web page from the browser an Internal server error is shown.

  - Wsgi error logged describing issue ( invalid syntax ) with the flask_wtf csrf.py file

Logged Wsgi error (image captured)

[wsgi error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1oqT.png)

I tried previous versions of flask_wtf because there were changes to the code in the csrf.py regarding how the validation errors were handled for the csrf tokens.

Result: Regardless of the latest version or past versions the change did not make a difference.The syntax error was still showing for the same section of code regarding csrf token validation.

Flask/WTF Versions:

Flask 2.0.2,
Flask-WTF 1.0.0,
WTForm 3.0.0

Python version 3.6.9 , Flask WTF should support > 3.6

Not sure if this is a bug with the package or something that I am doing wrong

Flask excerpt:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from DB_Insertdata import add_data
import datetime
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.update(
    SECRET_KEY="Secret_key",
    WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY="a csrf secret key"
)

csrf = CSRFProtect()
csrf.init_app(app)
```

HTML excerpt:

```
        <div id="Form">
            <form action='/' method='POST' autocomplete="off">
                <!--     {{ form.csrf_token }}    -->
                <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <div id="name">
                    <div id="name_label"> {{ form.entered_name.label }} </div> {{ form.entered_name() }} </div>
                <div id="email">
                    <div id="email_label"> {{ form.entered_email.label }} </div> {{ form.entered_email() }} </div>
                <div id="submitbtn"> {{ form.submit }} </div>
            </form>
```

Apache Config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    
    ServerName wordr.com
    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/wordr/wordr.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/wordr>
    WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /static /var/www/wordr/static

    <Directory /var/www/wordr/static/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/wordr/logs/error.log
    CustomLog  /var/www/wordr/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Upgraded mod_wsgi and the script was able to be ran.
apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

Issue:
Python 3.6.9 was in my system path but mod_wsgi version Python2.7 was being used because mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/2.7 was configured.

Note:Flask-WTF 15.0 and later support was dropped for anything earlier than Python 3.6.